# Los archivos js ligados al mismo html comparten scope?

Tags: javascript, html, css

estaba intentando hacer una portada para mi pagina y use el mismo nombre de variable para el mismo elemento `html` desde dos archivos `js` diferentes, el navegador dio error de referencia, ***a que se debe esto? los archivos js ligados a un mismo html comparten scope?***

Comment: Si lo comparten, de ahí el tema que puedas integrar alguna librería (como socket io) y usarla en otro archivo totalmente distinto

Comment: El hecho de que compartan scope es una de las razones por las cuales no es conveniente usar variables globales. De hecho los "bundlers" (empaquetadores) como webpack ponen todos los js en un solo js.